# Take snap from Raspberry pi using motion

Tags: webcam, motion

I need to take a snap of current image using motion. Since motion is running as a daemon I cannot take snap using fswebcam as it shows

> Device or Resource is busy.

So i need a command or interrupt for motion to take a snap pf current and save it in folder

Answer (score 3):

You can request that motion take a snapshot at any time via its web interface.  From a command line on the Raspberry Pi running motion, use

```
curl -s -o /dev/null http://picam1:8080/0/action/snapshot
```

This will silently request that motion take a snapshot and discard the response.   A symbolic link, lastsnap.jpg, in the motion file directory, will point to the snapshot itself.

See http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/RemoteControlHttpfor details on using http commands to control motion.

Answer (score 2):

You could script it with a simple oneliner
`/etc/init.d/motion stop && fswebcam && /etc/init.d/motion start`

Replace or append fswebcam with the commands/parameters that you need

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to snap a picture on demand, or just at a regular sequence? Motion can take snapshots at regular intervals. I've used it to create time lapse sequences. If this sounds useful, check out the *snapshot_interval* and related settings in the motion manpage.